# How to post "amount" variable in a Braintree JS secure custom form?

Tags: javascript, python, braintree

Is it possible to send your amount at the same time as your payment form when using braintree? The Braintree guide explicitly says:

"Make sure you don't include `name` attributes in your form elements. If the form is accidentally submitted and name attributes are present, sensitive data can reach your server."

So if using this simple implementation in HTML:

```
<form id="checkout" action="/your/server/endpoint" method="post">
   <input data-braintree-name="number" value="4111111111111111">
   <input data-braintree-name="expiration_date" value="10/20">
   <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Pay">
</form>
```

And my Python endpoint looks like this:

```
@app.route('/payment', methods=['POST'])
#@cross_origin()
def do_payment():

nonce = request.form["payment_method_nonce"]
result = braintree.Transaction.sale({
"amount": amount,
"payment_method_nonce":nonce,
"options": {
    "submit_for_settlement": True
    }
})
```

`

Is it then possible to send the amount in a post without messing up the encryption for the credit card information ? Or do I need to implement a second AJAX callback POST and persist somehow in the Python backend or implement som kind of sessions handling in Flask ?

What are my alternatives and best practice ? 
FYI: everything works as it is (if setting the amount to a static "10" for instance, the only thing missing is the amount variable in the backend since I can't send it using the payment form submit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<sub>I work at Braintree. If you have more questions, I suggest you [reach out to our support team](https://support.braintreepayments.com/).</sub>

It looks like you're using CSE, a deprecated integration method. I recommend you follow the Braintree docs and [use v.zero instead](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/javascript+python/start/overview).

If you put `amount` in the form, the user can change the value to whatever they want. That usually isn't the intended behavior, so you generally don't want `amount` to be part of the form. Instead, include a hidden field with an identifier for the item they're purchasing, or something like that.

The recommendation to not use `name` on your form fields only applies to fields with sensitive information you're intending to encrypt. It's fine to include `name` on fields that don't contain sensitive data.

Comment: The reason I put it up on Stack was that I thought that someone else might benefit from the answer, but I'll contact support directly in the future. Thanks!
PS. Perhaps you could clarify that section that not using "name" attribute is only important for fields sending sensitive data, and not the entire form.

Comment: @AndreasKlintberg I'm not sure how to clarify beyond restating it. Any field with a `name` attribute is sent on form submit; any field without it is not. You *never* want unencrypted credit card information sent to your server, so you *never* include a `name` attribute on those fields. It's fine to use the form to send other data to your server though, so for those fields you have to set a `name` attribute.